# How do I use the mousein event in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events

There are two pointer exit events: `mouseout` and `mouseleave`.

The difference between the two is that `mouseleave` fires only when the pointer leaves the watched element, while `mouseout` fires when the pointer leaves the watched element **or any of its children**.

When you move the pointer in and out of an element, `mouseleave` fires exactly once, while `mouseout` may fire more than once, depending on the number of children you hovered over.

**The question is: where is the `mousein` equivalent of `mouseout`?** On MDN, only `mouseleave`, `mouseout` and `mouseenter` [are documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter).

For a rare use case, I need to run code on every element that the pointer enters, including dynamically created ones. `mousein` would solve this for me, but it does not seem to exist anymore.

Comment: Afaik, I thought the pairing of `mouseout` and `mouseleave` were related to the pairing of `mouseover` and `mouseenter`

Comment: Emmm... Have forgot about [**`mouseover`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover)?

Comment: I mean it links to it in the second paragraph of that mdn page linked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is: where is the `mousein` equivalent of `mouseout`

The corresponding event to `mouseout` is `mouseover`, and for `mouseleave` it is `mouseenter`.

Their main difference is that that `mouseleave`/`mouseenter` does not bubble, which is well explained in e.g. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave), but in short

- `mouseleave` is fired when the pointer has exited the element and all of its descendants, whereas `mouseout` is fired when the pointer leaves the element or leaves one of the element's descendants (even if the pointer is still within the element).
- `mouseover`, it differs from `mouseenter` in that it doesn't bubble and that it isn't sent when the pointer is moved from one of its descendants' physical space to its own physical space.

Comment: Ah, I thought that `mouseover` is equivalent of `mousemove`.

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov No, `mousemove` doesn't have a corresponding event. The one's left is `mousedown`/`mouseup`, so all in all, 7 events, 3 pairs and 1 single